# when we write multiple values in taginputs and press enter, form submits. How to prevent this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-tags-input

here is my view code:

```
<table class="form-table" id="customFields">
  <tr>
    <td>Answer Variants</td>
    <td>Right Answer</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="" data-role="tagsinput" name="data[Answer][answer_name]" required/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="" data-role="tagsinput" name="data[Answer][right_answer]" required/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

here is my js code

```
$('.taginput').tagsinput();
```

In this, when i write some value in input and press enter for wrinting section second value, it submits the form. Anyone have solution then please share with me.

Comment: If you include an actual `submit` button in your form, this won't happen.

Comment: I think, this happens because we press enter when we write multiple values in taginputs. please help me out of this problem

Comment: It happens because you don't have an actual `submit` button in your form.